# header my account dropdown not showing magento2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, xml, customer-account, header

I have been trying to add my account drop down menu in my magento website. I found that it is there in luma theme by default. But my base theme is magento/blank. My account links are displayed in a single line one by one, not as drop down. I have created `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/layout/default.xml` and added the below code.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <attribute name="class" value="oothu-body-test"/>


    <referenceBlock name="header.links">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Customer" name="customer" template="account/customer.phtml" before="-"/>
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link-login" template="account/link/authorization.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>



    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header" name="header" as="header">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">welcome</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>


    <move element="header" destination="header.links" before="-"/>
    <move element="register-link" destination="header.links"/>
    <move element="top.links" destination="customer"/>
    <move element="authorization-link" destination="top.links" after="-"/>

</body>
```

Suddenly my account links are disappeared. I checked the

```
app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/account/customer.php
```

file and I found out this page is not calling. I had added some sample data to that page before `<?php if($block->customerLoggedIn()): ?>`, but it is not showing on front end. Can any one please guide me?